# Use Linq to join an object's list with its ID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

Sorry, I'm a little new to linq, but I think that's what I need help with...

I have a list of objects - employees for a task - and it has areas of expertise as a list of integers in the employee object. I need to be able to filter the employee list for only those with certain areas of expertise. But, I also want to be able to rank the employees by how many areas of expertise they match.

My thought was to create a list with (EmployeeID, Tag) with one entry for each employee tag, and then to join that with my search list, then aggregate by employee ID, count tags, then sort descending by the count.

But, I don't know how to create that list. How do I get the (EmployeeID, Tag) list?

I basically have:

Employee

- EmployeeID as Integer
- AreasOfExpertise as list(of Integer)

and I want a list of employee ID and AreaOfExpertiseID with one entry for each employee area of expertise.

Anybody know how I'd do that?

Thanks

Comment: Too much reading, too many special terms only you  know(f.e. _"employee area of expertis"_), hence too abstract. Show your class and 2-3 sample objects. It's also  difficult to see what the real problem or a desired output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var emplist = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 1, AreaOfExpertieseId = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 } },
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 2, AreaOfExpertieseId = new List<int>() { 1, 2 } },
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 3, AreaOfExpertieseId = new List<int>() },
                new Employee { EmployeeId = 4, AreaOfExpertieseId = new List<int>() { 1,4 } },
            };
        var expertiseId = new[] {2,3}; //ExpertiseIds you want to search;
        var emps = emplist.Where(e => e.AreaOfExpertieseId.Exists(id => expertiseId.Contains(id)))
            .Select(e => new {e.EmployeeId, Rank = e.AreaOfExpertieseId.Count }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful. I ended up using a slightly different approach, but your post was very informative.

Comment: @Mike - Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped your or solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of thing that you are looking for?  This will make an anonymous type with 2 properties, but that could just as easily be what ever type you want.

```
        var employees = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5};
        var skills = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>() 
        { 
            new KeyValuePair<int, String>(1, "test"), 
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "test3"), 
            new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "test4") 
        };

        var list = 
        (
            from employee in employees 
            join skill in skills 
                on employee equals skill.Key 
            select new { employee, skill.Value }
        ).ToList();
```

EDIT:
Without more information on what your code currently is, I just took a guess at some types that will show how to access properties and do the join.  If you update, I'm happy to make this more specific to your needs.

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join) is another good example of join syntax that might be helpful to you

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something related to the answers here, but slightly different. Sorry, this was my fault, I'm a little new to this and didn't provide helpful information. I had this:

```
Class Employee
    Public EmployeeID as Integer
    Public Skills as list(of Integer)
End Class

'Should turn a list of EmployeeID, MatchingSkillCount
Function FindEmployeesWithMatchingSkills(Employees as List(of Employee), SearchSkills as List(of Integer)) as IEnumerable(of KeyValuePair(of Integer, Integer))

End Function
```

But, I couldn't figure it out. With a little help, I came up with this, which seems to work:

```
Function FindEmployeesWithMatchingSkills(Employees as List(of Employee), SearchSkills as List(of Integer)) as IEnumerable(of KeyValuePair(of Integer, Integer))
    Return (From e in Employees Select New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(e.EmployeeID, e.Skills.Where(Function(s) SearchSkills.Contains(s)).Count)).OrderByDescending(Function(kvp) kvp.Value).Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Value > 0)
End Function
```

Thank you everyone for your help!